# Disable adding/deleting items on Sales Order

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have looked through a lot of Netsuite's documentation and searched on stackoverflow and do not see this currently answered.

I basically want to lock down (disable end user from changing) certain fields on a Sales Order that affect margin after certain conditions are met. I have been able to lock down the fields I wanted on the item level, but I realized they can still add/copy/delete an item, which affects margin as well.

I do *not* want to lock down the entire item sublist - we want them to be able to edit minor things, but the actual items cannot be added/copied/deleted.

Any ideas how I can do this? Basically somehow remove the buttons for add/copy/remove?

EDIT:
Due to the removal of my Javascript tag, I will explain it's purpose. This removal, because at the line level, I know will need to be done in SuiteScript- Javascript using NetSuite's API. It is relevant to note this is the language I am trying to utilize.

Code: To explain what I have done so far, below is some pseudocode:

```
function pageInit(){
if(currDate >= dLockDate && type == 'edit'){        
    //lock SO Date (header level)
    nlapiDisableField('trandate', true);                        
}
}
```

In lineInit://locks down some fields at the line item level

```
function lineInit(){
if(type == 'item'){
//list of items to disable
    var a_itemDisFields = ['rate', 'quantity','porate','amount', 'item'];

    for(var i = 0; i < a_itemDisFields.length; i++){
        nlapiDisableLineItemField('item',a_itemDisFields[i] , true);
    }

}
```

}

Similiar to the above two functions, where I disable fields, I want to disable the ability to add a line item. I do NOT want to lock the whole record (as I am aware I can do from a Workflow), but rather I want to stop users from being able to add/copy/delete Items in the Item sublist.

Comment: Do you have an code or a physical example to show us? the question is quite hard to conceptualize as it stands.

Comment: Thank you for asking clarification and not just voting this down. I guess if you are familiar with NetSuite and working with Item Sublists, these buttons are at the line level. For each exting line item in the sublist, when you click on it (in edit mode) you can see Make Copy and Remove. For a new line you see Add. I want to disable/remove those 3 buttons/functionality.

There is nlapiDisableField and nlapiDisableLineItemField in the NS API. Neither disables actions (such as adding/copying/removing a line).

Comment: I am not familiar with it, I was just offering advice on how to get some answers to your issue (I follow the JS tag)

Comment: I appreciate the advise and helping me clarifying instead of merely voting it down!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `validateLine` event in your client script to prevent users from adding lines when certain conditions are met. The function you use simply needs to return a Boolean value: `true` if the line addition can continue, `false` if it should not.

Similarly, there is a `validateDelete` event you can use to prevent line removal when certain conditions are met.

Lastly, and also following a similar pattern, there is a `validateField` event you can use to prevent the user from modifying a field value when certain conditions are met. It is not quite disabling the field, but it will prevent them from changing the value.

Adding these event handler functions to your client script should allow you to prevent the changes you desire, though it does not actually disable any of the fields.

You *could* use jQuery to disable the Add/Copy/Remove buttons and certain fields, but I doubt that NetSuite would consider that a "supported" approach.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I knew of the validateLine function, but not the validateDelete. Thank you!!